# My php-based client IP tracker doesn't always trigger, why?

Tags: php, ip, client, tracking

**UPDATE** Nevermind it is working fine, I wrote it so that if the same website was viewed more than once it wasn't added again rather incremented... haha I don't know my own code

I wrote this script here, it is somewhat redundant as it writes into two different tables but the only difference is that one counts views and the other one counts new ips. I suppose I could redo them.

The problem is that the tracker isn't always triggered. Why would that be?

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',true);

function track() {

$ip = "my ip";

$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'dbconnect.php');
$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if($client_ip!=$ip){

$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT website_url FROM website_views where website_url=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$actual_link);

if($stmt->execute())
{
    // means it exists
    $stmt->bind_result($website_url_from_db);
    if($stmt->fetch())
    {
    $link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
    $id = "";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE website_views SET views=views+1 where website_url=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$actual_link);
    $stmt->execute();

    $link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
    $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT client_ip FROM views where client_ip=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$client_ip);
    if($stmt->execute()){

    $link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE views SET num_times=num_times+1 where client_ip=? and website_url=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$client_ip,$actual_link);
    $stmt->execute();

    }else{

    $num_times = 1;
    $link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO views VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('issi',$id,$actual_link,$client_ip,$num_times);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    }else{
$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
$id = "";
$website_url = $actual_link;
$views = 1;
$ip = $client_ip;
$num_times=1;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO website_views VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('isi',$id,$website_url,$views);
$stmt->execute();
$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO views VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('issi',$id,$actual_link,$client_ip,$num_times);
$stmt->execute();
}

}
}
}

track();

?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Where? How do you just say that haha... Btw... you have cancer, but I won't tell you where. $actual_link?

Comment: Thanks I modified them, the problem is still that only certain pages trigger the tracking even though they all have this. What could cause the difference? I'm wondering if I should trigger it by onload instead using ajax rather than php only

Comment: When you say the track() fx is not always triggered, how do you know that (other than the obvious no sql call)?  Are you sure you're getting into the fx every time?  Is there an if block or something else that would prevent track from being initially called - something that isn't being shown here?

Comment: This is the entire code, I include it at the top of every website. I get into phpmyadmin, I test a working site, increments, test a different site, does not increment. So I'm wondering why it doesn't work in some cases. I'm using tor browser to get a different IP and I realize since my IP is dynamic the declaration of a fixed IP at the top for comparison is bad, ideally in the future I would use session value eg. logging in, but not every website of mine requires logging in. It also seems like a pain in the ass to include all of this in every page even a require file and transferring folders.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when is it ever safe to set something equal to something like I guess it would be a variable is when it is not safe? Or is it never safe hence the use of a parametrized variable?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ipAddress = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}
```

also, check the print_r( $_SERVER ) to make sure it's giving you what you expect.

Comment: What is this for? I'll look into array_key_exists